Handling JSON Object Field in Flutter API Call
I have code that needs to store data from an API call, which returns a list of exams correctly. However, when I try to save this list of exams using a controller based on the ExamData model, I encounter issues with the "status" field. This field is an object containing attributes like grade, date, and honors. I'm struggling to handle this field, as removing it allows the exams to load correctly, but including it causes issues.
Controller:
Future<List<ExamData>> fetchAllExamStudent(User student, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
        // Wait for the API response to complete
        final List<ExamData> responseData = await apiService.getStudentExams(student, context);
        print('Lunghezza lista${responseData.length}');

        if (responseData.isNotEmpty) {
            print('\n\nPrimo elemento della lista:');
            print(responseData.first);
        } else {
            print('\n\nLa lista è vuota.');
        }

        return responseData;
    } catch (e) {
        throw Exception('Errore Caricamento Esami');
    }
}

API Service:
Future<List<ExamData>> getStudentExams(User student, BuildContext context) async {
    const String matId = "000000"; // Il mio codice matId per test
    final url = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/v2/students/myExams/$matId');

    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode("${student.username}:${student.password}"))}',
    });

    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
        print('\nallExam:\n $jsonData');
        return jsonData.map((data) => ExamData.fromJson(data)).toList();
    } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        throw Exception('Errore del SERVER durante il caricamento degli esami dello studente');
    } else {
        throw Exception('\nErrore durante caricamento esami dello studente');
    }
}

Model Exam:
class ExamData {
    String? nome;
    String? codice;
    String? tipo;
    int? adId;
    int? adsceID;
    String? docente;
    String? docenteID;
    String? semestre;
    String? semestreDes;
    String? adLogId;
    String? domPartCod;
    Status status;

    ExamData({
        required this.nome,
        required this.codice,
        required this.tipo,
        required this.adId,
        required this.adsceID,
        required this.docente,
        required this.docenteID,
        required this.semestre,
        required this.semestreDes,
        required this.adLogId,
        required this.domPartCod,
        required this.status,
    });

    factory ExamData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        try {
            return ExamData(
                nome: json['nome'] as String?,
                codice: json['codice'] as String?,
                tipo: json['tipo'] as String?,
                adId: json['adId'] as int?,
                adsceID: json['adsceID'] as int?,
                docente: json['docente'] as String?,
                docenteID: json['docenteID'] as String?,
                semestre: json['semestre'] as String?,
                semestreDes: json['semestreDes'] as String?,
                adLogId: json['adLogId'] as String?,
                domPartCod: json['domPartCod'] as String?,
                status: Status.fromJson(json['status']),
            );
        } catch (e) {
            throw FormatException('Errore durante il parsing del JSON: $e');
        }
    }
}

class Status {
    String? esito;
    int? voto;
    int? lode;
    String? data;

    Status({
        required this.esito,
        required this.voto,
        required this.lode,
        required this.data
    });

    factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        try {
            return Status(
                esito: json['esito'] as String?,
                voto: json['voto'] as int?,
                lode: json['lode'] as int?,
                data: json['data'] as String?
            );
        } catch (e) {
            throw FormatException('Errore durante il parsing del JSON STATUS: $e');
        }
    }
}

I tried doing it this way, but I always get the exception 'Error Loading Exams' in the fetchAllExamStudent() function.
factory ExamData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    try {
        return ExamData(
            nome: json['nome'] as String?,
            codice: json['codice'] as String?,
            tipo: json['tipo'] as String?,
            adId: json['adId'] as int?,
            adsceID: json['adsceID'] as int?,
            docente: json['docente'] as String?,
            docenteID: json['docenteID'] as String?,
            semestre: json['semestre'] as String?,
            semestreDes: json['semestreDes'] as String?,
            adLogId: json['adLogId'] as String?,
            domPartCod: json['domPartCod'] as String?,
            status: json['status'] != null ? Status.fromJson(json['status']) : null,
            cfu: json['CFU'] as int?,
            annoId: json['annoId'] as int?,
            numAppelliPrenotabili: json['numAppelliPrenotabili'] as int?,
            tipoInsDes: json['tipoInsDes'] as String?,
            tipoInsCod: json['tipoInsCod'] as String?,
            tipoEsaDes: json['tipoEsaDes'] as String?,
        );
    } catch (e) {
        throw FormatException('Errore durante il parsing del JSON: $e');
    }
}


add error data like error text from debug console or terminal.

This is the error, namely the exception capture:
flutter: Error during _allExamStudent() Exception: Loading Exams Error FormatException: Error parsing JSON: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int?' in type cast.

If your error is like double is not a subtype of int? In the Status model then in your response lote or voto field might be double but you thing it is int? which is not true. So, check which field has double type data and change the data type of that variable.

I got there, the problem is that the API always returns me a 'grade' in this format 22.0 therefore double, in some cases in the 'grade' field the null value as there are exams without a grade and therefore I assume it doesn't suit them. I can't handle this

Now your problem is solved or still you phase any issue?

A way to solve the problem is to use num? instead of int? or double?.
